# Call a function in a parsed Jint program

Tags: jint

I use Jint to parse JS code and call functions in it. As I use a multithreaded environment, I use the program-parsing approach as indicated in the response to this issue: https://github.com/sebastienros/jint/issues/384

So what I have is a `Jint.Parser.Ast.Program` instance. I can iterate through the `IFunctionDeclaration`s in it and find my functions. But I don't know how to actually call the functions...

```vb
Dim parser As New Jint.Parser.JavaScriptParser
Dim program As Jint.Parser.Ast.Program = parser.Parse(code)

For Each func As Jint.Parser.IFunctionDeclaration In program.FunctionDeclarations
    If func.Id.Name = myFunctionName Then
        ' How to call the function?
    End If
Next
```

I only found a way to execute the whole `Program`. I assume that I must do that, so that the functions are actually defined in an engine. But still, how can I call a certain function in my script?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do this. You only want to call your function if it is defined in the script? Why do you need a parser to do this, you can just try to call it if it's defined, is this an optimization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your program is executed, just use the same method to execute your function. Example is c#

```cs
var parser = new Jint.Parser.JavaScriptParser();
// _parserCache is a static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Jint.Parser.Ast.Program>
var program = _parserCache.GetOrAdd(scriptName, key => parser.Parse(code));

foreach (var func in program.FunctionDeclarations)
{
    if (func.Id.Name == myFunctionName)
    {
        var exec = new Engine();
        // The entire program is executed, to define the function
        exec.Execute(program);
        // now you can call your function
        exec.Execute($"{myFunctionName}()");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is basically what I came up with, too. I just use `exec.Invoke(myFunctionName, params)` to pass arguments. I was wondering if there was a way to call a function without executing the program, but there isn't